# Problem integrating jeditable in cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, jeditable

I have integrated jquery jeditable in my project.

```
$(function() {
  $(".editable_textarea").editable("/articles/edit/", { 
      indicator : "<img src='img/indicator.gif'>",
      type   : 'textarea',
      select : true,
      submit : 'OK',
      cancel : 'cancel',
      cssclass : "editable",
      method : 'POST',
  });
});
```

Now when I click on the `div.editable_textarea`  you see textarea with ok button. Now when make changes and click on **OK**. In my controller action `/articles/edit`, I am simple print `$this->data`.

It prints `Array()(`empty array).

No data is sent to controller. I also tried `$this->params['url'].`

It prints `Array('URL' => '/articles/edit').`

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: @alexdd55 You are right. It showed all the variables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not named it

```
$(function() {
  $(".editable_textarea").editable("/articles/edit/", { 
      indicator : "<img src='img/indicator.gif'>",
      type   : 'textarea',
      name   : 'data[Articles][desc]',
      select : true,
      submit : 'OK',
      cancel : 'cancel',
      cssclass : "editable",
      method : 'POST',
  });
});
```

and you can access this in your controller like

```
echo $this->data['Articles']['desc'];
```

You can go with [this](http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2008/02/24/edit-in-place-with-jquery-and-cakephp/) for your more info